# IdentityServer4 CORS Settings with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4, openid

EDIT:
I partially answered my question. For those who are curious, there is another table inside the database called `ClientProperties` that you can use to set other properties not on the main client table. I did this, but I still have an error:
[image]

My entry for the client config looks like this:
[image]

Working on it further (I manually defined the content policy), this is the error that is present that I am stuck at:
[image]

--------------------- Original Question ---------------------

I have IdentityServer4 setup using EntityFramework for my configuration and operation data.

I ran into an issue when trying to allow ajax to handle the redirects when logging into an application. Instead of trying to hardcode everything, I was trying to setup CORS within IDS4.

I was reading the document [HERE](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html). It talks about setting up `AllowedCorsOrigins` on the client so that the identity server will correctly setup CORS. The issue I am having is that in the database, the clients do not have a column called `AllowedCorsOrigins` defined. In fact there are a lot of missing columns as defined on the openId [model](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html#refclient).

On my identity server, my DI configuration is as follows:

```cs
services.AddIdentity < IdentityUser, IdentityRole > ()
  .AddUserManager < ApplicationUserManager < IdentityUser >> ()
  .AddSignInManager < ApplicationSignInManager < IdentityUser >> ()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores < ApplicationDbContext > ();

services.AddIdentityServer()
  .AddAspNetIdentity < IdentityUser > ()
  .AddConfigurationStore(options => {
    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(
      configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"),
      opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(startupName));
  })
  .AddOperationalStore(options => {
    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(
      configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"),
      opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(startupName));
  })
  .AddProfileService < ApplicationProfileService < IdentityUser >> ()
  .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

And on my client the DI setup is as follows:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
  }).AddCookie("cookie")
  .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
    options.Authority = appSettings.App.AuthorityUrl;
    options.ClientId = appSettings.App.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = appSettings.App.ClientSecret;

    options.ResponseType = ResponseTypes.Code;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.ResponseMode = "query";

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("nickname", "nickname", "nickname");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Picture, JwtClaimTypes.Picture, JwtClaimTypes.Picture);
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

    var test = options.ClaimActions;

    options.Scope.Add(appSettings.App.Scopes[0]);
    options.SaveTokens = true;
  });
```

I am having trouble figuring out where I should be defining the `AllowedCorsOrigins` as all of the examples I have seen are in memory examples. I would think this property should be in the database on the client table...

Here is a look at what values I have access to in the database:

[image: Database Table]

Finally this is the error in the console:
[image: Console Error]

Comment: what browser do you use? do you get this error on Chrome?

Comment: @nahidf I just figured out the issue, ajax post will not let you do a 302 redirect. I have to handle this in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with AJAX.

Because I post a form to the login endpoint in MVC, the response can not be a 302 redirect. This is because AJAX does not allow redirects on posts.

To fix this, I am now returning a JSON object with the return URL and having javascript set the `window.location` value instead. The following is an example of this (Note I am checking if it is a JSON object first because this handler handles multiple ajax calls).

```js
if (xhr.responseText.startsWith('{')) {
    let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (json.ok) {
        window.location = json.redirect;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to define domains where a client may request to login from you will want to set that up in the `ClientCorsOrigins` table.  In there you'll define a web address, like `https://www.example.com` and the ID of the client from the `Clients` table.

However if you are trying to define CORS configuration for other API calls against Identity Server you'll need to define that in your `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                "http://www.contoso.com");
        });
});
```

Comment: Already tried to do all of this. See my previous answer. Can't do a 302 redirect within an AJAX post response. Thanks though! Still good info for others.